# In what ways were the philosophies of William James and Kierkegaard similar?

Tags: christianity, kierkegaard, william-james

Especially with regards to the justification of having religious belief- were they both fideists?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. One-line posts are discouraged because it is hard to tell from them what people are looking for. Kierkegaard and James did both advocate faith based beliefs, but their reasons for doing so (religious fervor vs pragmatic attitude) were so different that I am not sure applying the fideist label to both is of much use, see descriptions under [SEP's fideism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fideism/#2.2).

Answer (score 2):

They both were energized by their opposition to Hegel's absolute.  Kierkegaard criticized Hegel for thinking of everything but Hegel.  James championed free will and,at most,a partnership with--not a complete absorption into--God.